# I am unable to understand back propagation algorithm,how to update weights using delta. Can anyone help me?

Tags: java

for input to first hidden layer

```
            for(int j=0;j<hiddenNeuronInLayer;j++)
             {
                for(int k=0;k<inputNeuron;k++)
                {
                    netInput[j]+=input[k]*weight[count];
                    count++;

                }
                netInput[j]+=bais[0];
                hiddenOutput[0][j]=(1/(1+Math.exp(-netInput[j])));
             }
```

for  Encoder

```
             for(int j=1;j<hiddenLayer;j++)
             {
                 for(int k=0;k<hiddenNeuronInLayer;k++)
                 {
                    for(int p=0;p<hiddenNeuronInLayer;p++)
                    {
                         netInput[k]+=hiddenOutput[j-1][p]*weight[count++];
                         //System.out.println(count);
                    }
                    netInput[k]+=bais[j];
                    hiddenOutput[j][k]=(1/(1+Math.exp(-netInput[k])));
                 }

             }
```

for Decoder

```
         int layer=hiddenLayer-1;
             while(layer>0)
             {
                 for(int k=0;k<hiddenNeuronInLayer;k++)
                 {
                    for(int p=0;p<hiddenNeuronInLayer;p++)
                    {
                         netInput[k]+=hiddenOutput[layer][p]*weight[count++];
                         //System.out.println(count);
                    }
                    netInput[k]+=bais[layer-1];
                    hiddenOutput[layer-1][k]=(1/(1+Math.exp(-netInput[k])));
                 }
                 layer--;
             }
```

for output layer

```
         for(int j=0;j<outputNeuron;j++)
             {
                 for(int k=0;k<hiddenNeuronInLayer;k++)
                 {
                     output[j]+=hiddenOutput[layer][k]*weight[count++];
                     //System.out.println(count);
                 }
                 output[j]+=bais[layer];
                 output[j]=(1/(1+Math.exp(-output[j])));
              }
```

I am writting this code for autoencoder. After feed Forward network i am unable to use back propagaation algorithm.